# Positional parameter cannot be found error while using powershell to update Active Directory

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I'm attempting to update Active Directory user entries with a CSV.  When I run it I get the following error, and I cannot understand why.  The column containing the account name is not null.

```
    Set-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.
At line:2 char:11
+ Set-ADUSer <<<<  -Identity $_.sAMAccountName`
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

(repeat for each row in the CSV)
```

Here is my existing update script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$userList = Import-Csv '.\UpdatedUserInfo.csv'

$userList|Foreach{
Set-ADUSer -Identity $_.sAMAccountName`
-givenName = $user.givenName`
-initials = $user.initials`
-sn = $user.sn`
-cn = $user.name`
-displayName = $user.displayName`
-department = $user.department`
-telephoneNumber = $user.telephoneNumber`
-facsimileTelephoneNumber = $user.facsimileTelephoneNumber`
-mobile = $user.mobile`
-homePhone = $user.homePhone`
-company = $user.Company`
-physicalDeliveryOfficeName = $user.physicalDeliveryOfficeName`
-streetAddress = $user.streetAddress`
-l = $user.l`
-postOfficeBox = $user.postOfficeBox`
-state = $user.st`
-postalCode = $user.postalCode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell looking at the docs on this cmdlet, the parameters you've specified should not use `=` between the parameter name and the value.  Try getting rid of all the `=` chars.

If you do have a parameter that does take a hashtable then that parameter should be specified like so:

```
Set-ADUser -Replace @{name=_value_; name=_value_}
```